# Error: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

The environments I'm using are: .NET (2.0) and SQL Server 2005.

The scenario: in a .NET form the user gets prompted for two variables that will be provided to a stored procedure in SQL Server. Once the records are returned from the stored procedure, the .NET app will import these records to a `.csv` file.

The trick here is that the stored procedure is dynamic. The records returned are not always the same columns or populating the same temp table. The .NET app works when the stored procedure runs in less than 30 secs.

I have increase my `conn.CommandTimeout = 6000` in my app and I have increase the "remote query connection" in SQL Server to 6000 as well but it's still failing for those variables running longer then 30 secs.

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Chaydee

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you are setting the command timeout on the connection instead of the command object itself. Can't see your code but if you are using a DataReader, DataAdapter etc. try setting CommandTimeout on those objects. A few other possibilities:

1. the connection timeout is being exceeded before the query is being run. Not likely, but still, what is the connection timeout? It should be >= any CommandTimeout.
2. the CommandTimeout call is not being executed.
3. something else is later overriding the CommandTimeout call.

Comment: Aaron, sorry I should have include my code.  Not sure on what you mean by setting the commandTimout on object.  Thanks for the other suggestions. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Code:

 Private Function GetSampleData() As DataTable
        Dim DS As DataSet
        Dim objConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=***;Integrated Security=True;Packet Size=4096;Connect Timeout=0;Max Pool Size = 300")
        Dim objCmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim myDataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
        objCmd.CommandTimeout = 0


        myDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Hierarchy.GethierarchyTree", objConn)
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New param...blah.

Comment: I suggest you update the question with that code so that it is much more readable than in a comment (use the {} button).